# Perform Background tasks in windows 7 phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-process

In Android we have Services to perform background tasks what can we use to do same in Windows Phone ?

Comment: internet search drew a blank?

Answer (score 0):

[Background Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Scheduled Tasks and background agents allow an application to execute code in the background, even when the application is not running in the foreground.